# Running script on github page using jekyll

Tags: javascript, jekyll, github-pages

I have a problem having my origin version running a script I have in the index.html file.

The script runs fine locally if I have this in the index.html file:

```html
<script  src="{{ base.url | prepend: site.url }}/assets/js/script.js"></script>
```

If I have that previous code and I try to run on github, I get this:

[image: wrong github address]

(Wrong github address)

If I change the code in the index file to this:

```html
<script  src="{{ site.github.repository_url }}/tree/gh-pages/assets/js/script.js"></script>
```

Then the error is gone but the script still doesn't run and I get this:

```
Cross-Origin Read Blocking (CORB) blocked cross-origin response https://github.com/montythepython/mixedmessages/blob/gh-pages/assets/js/script.js with MIME type text/html. See https://www.chromestatus.com/feature/5629709824032768 for more details.
```

[image: right github address? but with an added "blob"]

(Right github address? But with an added "blob")

Which I am not sure what it means. Is it reading the script as a text file and because of it the script doesn't actually run?

Any help, very much appreciated
The project is here:
https://github.com/montythepython/mixedmessages

Comment: Why don't you just import your js file via a relative path? `<script src="/assets/js/script.js"></script>`

Comment: Thanks Dominik. From what I understand, gitpages puts the script under a different tree structure: `/tree/gh-pages/assets/js/script.js` If I do what you suggests, it works locally but breaks at origin

Comment: On your very page at https://montythepython.github.io/ you're doing `<link rel="stylesheet" href="/assets/css/style.css?v=2f500a37db754d128adfe22b97e69cc3e7fb5acb">` so I'd say that works ;)

Comment: "Which I am not sure what it means. Is it reading the script as a text file and because of it the script doesn't actually run?" — No, it's reading it as an HTML document because you are linking to an HTML page that shows a pretty formatted version of the code. Github repositories are not designed to be used as a CDN! Deploy the script to github-pages and figure out what the correct URL should be.

Comment: Hi @Dominik , yes you are right it works there although I dont fully understand the address. I dont know what it does with that `..?v=2f500...` section. But when I do it with the script, I get the error in the first image of my post. If you look at the address, it goes to the right place it needs to go locally but in github the location of the assets folder changes

Comment: Hi Quentin, if I understood correctly, what you are suggesting is what I am trying to do and think achieved. I managed to give the right location to the point I dont get the error regarding not finding the script. Now it seems it finds the script but it doesnt run it

Comment: I found a solution. First, the location I thought the script was (`/tree/gh-pages/assets/js/script.js`) seems is not the right place to look for it. So from Dominik's suggestion I realized I was missing the name of the repository if I did the relative path as suggested. I added the repository to the location: `<script  src="/mixedmessages/assets/js/script.js"></script>` and it now works. So, now it works. I just need to modify the code if I want to run locally. Thanks! There is probably a way to have one line only like everything so far that builds for local and works for origin as well.

Comment: GitHub pages doesn't change the location of static files. Does your script have a front matter? Or it is plain js?